# Correct way to interface with SelectedItems (IList / SelectedObjectCollection) in Listbox (view -> viewmodel)

Tags: c#, listbox, ilist

When interfacing with one item in a listbox, its simple enough to go:

```
  myClass citem = (myClass)myListBop.SelectedItem.
  viewModel.doSomethingWithItem(cItem)
```

Whats the correct way for multiple items? I have seen examples of simply copying the data to a List, but surely it would be best to avoid the copy and go for the correct cast? Resharper kindly informs me that I might be doing something wrong:

[image]

Where the suggestion is:

```
Suspicious case: there is no type in the solution which is inherited from both "Sytem.Windows.Forms.ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection" and "System,Collections.Generic.IList<myClass>"
```

Basically what is the intended usage of IList / SelectedObjectCollection?

Comment: There's no relation between:

    ListBox.SelectedObjectCollection and `IList<MyClass>`

Both of them have IList as the base class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whats the correct way for multiple items?

[`SelectedObjectCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedobjectcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) does not implement `IList<T>`. you can't just cast it. Instead you can use `Cast` method to cast all items to your type and put them in a list:

```
myListBop.SelectedItems.Cast<myClass>().ToList();
```

Comment: Do i need the "tolist" could I simply use the result? "IEnumerable"

Comment: @chrispepper1989 Cast won't be executed until you iterate over the result. ToList does the iteration. If you don't want to enumerate result immediately you can remove ToList